# Is Objective-C remote-message feature deprecated?

Tags: objective-c, language-features

I discovered there is some kind of remote-messaging feature *were* in Objective-C language. But it is no longer documented. Is it deprecated? What's happening in the feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean these:

[Distributed Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/DistrObjects.html)

Certainly not deprecated as far as I know. More usurped by other mechanisms.

Comment: Yeah -- it still exists but it is almost always the wrong solution.  As it turns out, a generic messaging system that works transparently over the wire with automatic proxying is, while quite cool, a fantastic way to right unusable software that is also impossible to debug. :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll be happier implementing remote messaging with something else. Distributed Objects is still available in the Cocoa framework, but it can be difficult to work with; eg lack of documentation and examples, and lots of gotchas.

ZeroMQ is third party technology for doing remote messaging. BLIP is yet another. There are Objective-C APIs for both.

You could also roll your own thing using JSON and NSURLConnection or embedded HTTP servers.